# RestAssured has set up a localized logging configuration, but the corresponding request logs do not appear when running a successful test

Tags: java, rest-assured

RestAssured api testing demo

```
package com.example;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.config.LogConfig;
import io.restassured.filter.log.LogDetail;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class TestDemo {

    @Test(description = "Verify that the Get Post API returns correctly")
    public void verifyGetAPI() {

        LogConfig logConfig = LogConfig.logConfig().enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails(LogDetail.ALL).enablePrettyPrinting(true);

        // Given
        given()
                .config(RestAssured.config().logConfig(logConfig))
                .baseUri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")

                // When
                .when()
                .get("/posts/1")

                // Then
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
    }

}
```

Define a LogConfig configuration in the test method that prints a log regardless of whether the request succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```java
RestAssured
        .given()
        .log().everything(true)
        .baseUri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")

        // When
        .when()
        .get("/posts/1")

        // Then
        .then()
        .statusCode(200);
```

Comment: This does work, but it doesn't use the logging configuration

Answer (score 0):

> Define a LogConfig configuration in the test method that prints a log
> regardless of whether the request succeeds or fails.

You mean print log of both request and response? then NO way to do it using `LogConfig`.

Solution: use `RequestLoggingFilter` & `ResponseLoggingFilter`, because `LogConfig` is just a shortcut for RequestLoggingFilter and ResponseLoggingFilter.

```java
RestAssured.filters(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter());
```

or

```java
RestAssured
        .given()
        .filters(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter())
        ...
```